# Does express.js create folder to mirror javascript files?

Tags: node.js, express

I've just checked out a [nodejs-expressjs-boilerplate](https://github.com/skaapgif/webapp-boilerplate/tree/master/web) project. After I ran it I've discovered there are a lot of directories mirrored from root 'web/' to newly-created 'public/' directory.

I'm writing here because it looks this question is not covered well in the documentation (Or I'm bad at googling expressjs docs, sorry).

- is that true that 'public/' directory in the project root contains copies of files inside 'web/...' directory?
- When these copies are created?
- Are javascript files from 'public/' executed or from 'web/'?
- Do you experience the same behaviour? Is that expressjs feature or project-specific?
- Why 'public/' directory is not in '.gitignore'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that true that 'public/' directory in the project root contains copies of files inside 'web/...' directory
>   When these copies are created?

The [Gruntile](https://github.com/skaapgif/webapp-boilerplate/blob/master/Gruntfile.coffee) specifies that, yes. At build time files are compiled/copied.
This task is performed when you execute `npm start`, as you could see from [package.json](https://github.com/skaapgif/webapp-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json#L6) it calls `grunt` which executes its default task.

> Are javascript files from 'public/' executed or from 'web/'?

In web you have `.coffee` files, those cannot be run in the browser, that is why there's the need for a dir that holds the compiled `.js` files.

> Do you experience the same behaviour? Is that expressjs feature or project-specific?

This tasks are performed by [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), express could be used without these features, also without the Jade templates for instance. It depends on what you need.

> Why 'public/' directory is not in '.gitignore'?

I honestly don't know, ask the author :D